# Can I invoke a Fle Explorer for a particular directory in code?

Tags: android, file, file-browser

I have a directory on SD card where my application writes some output files to.

From my code I want to invoke a File Explorer (such as 'My Files' on my Samsung phone or any other file explorer, if installed) so it goes to my directory and shows the list of my files in there.

Can I do such a thing? It seems there's no such intent defined?